# Flutter WebRTC streaming video from server

Tags: dart, flutter, webrtc

I'm using WebRTC to streaming video from server. WebRTC for flutter just release a while ago, not much documentation on there. What I want to know is how to detect if iceCandidate is on and not null. How to check if iceConnectionState == Connected or not?

```
stream() async{
    Map<String,dynamic> configuration = {
      "iceServers" : []
    };

    final Map<String, dynamic> constraints = {
      "mandatory": {},
      "optional": [ {"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": false}, ],
    };

    peerConnection = await createPeerConnection(configuration, constraints);
    print('ok');
    peerConnection.onIceCandidate = gotIceCandidate;
    peerConnection.onIceConnectionState = onIceState;
  }

  void gotIceCandidate(RTCIceCandidate iceCandidate){
    if (iceCandidate.candidate != null){
      print("onIceCandidate");
    }
 }

  void onIceState(RTCIceConnectionState iceConnectionState){
    if (iceConnectionState.index == 3){//CONNECTED
      print("connected");
    }else if(iceConnectionState.index == 5){//FAILED
      print("failed");
    }
  }
```

There is no [onconnectedstatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/oniceconnectionstatechange) on this flutter plugin. And no [onTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/ontrack) to stream a video from server. Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: You've mentioned that you are using a Flutter plugin and could you provide which plugin are you using and [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, I've noticed that there is an available plugin for this. Are you referring to this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc)?

Answer (score 0):

[flutter_webrtc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc/) has `RTCPeerConnection().iceConnectionState` property that you can use as mentioned in their [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_webrtc/latest/flutter_webrtc/RTCPeerConnection/iceConnectionState.html). Similarly, `onTrack` is also [available on the same class](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_webrtc/latest/flutter_webrtc/RTCPeerConnection/onTrack.html).